# What does "frame" as referrer mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, garbage-collection

I need to process a large number (40,000+) of zip files. I've written code that opens each zip file, extracts the information needed from the files, and inserts the key information into a database. Everything works just fine when I run it for a single zip. However, when I start running the program to process everything it crashes.

I watched the memory allocation using the `top` command and could see that the memory consumption was steadily growing. I'm not using any libraries outside what comes with Python3 so it isn't some custom code where I forgot to release something.

I looked at `gc.get_referrers()` for some objects before the main processing function returns and I see this:

```
[<frame at 0x232b270, file '/reports.py', line 179, code visit>, <frame at 0x171d840, file '/reports.py', line 179, code visit>]
```

I also looked at the garbage collection module and printed the output of `gc.get_stats()`. I understand what is each field, but I don't know how to interpret a list of these which is what the function returns. That being said, I'm printing the stats after the program finishes processing each zip and the `collected` field is not changing. I would have expected the number of objects collected to keep increasing as my program moved on to the next zip file.

```
[{'collections': 10441, 'collected': 351, 'uncollectable': 0},
 {'collections': 949, 'collected': 67, 'uncollectable': 0},
 {'collections': 39, 'collected': 26128, 'uncollectable': 0}]
```

I can't figure out how to find this memory leak. My best guess is there is an unreachable object referencing something that keeps it from getting garbage collected. The two referrer and garbage collection data is what I have so far, but I'm not familiar with how to get more information or how to run this down.

Comment: What do you mean by the statement "However, when I start running the program to process everything it crashes."  How is the 'crash' presented?  Do you get an error message, if so please post the entire error message from traceback to end as part of your question.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @itprorh66 It gets killed by the OS when the memory allocation gets too high so there's no error message.